# php 5.4 serialize vs row columns

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I need to add more faq in each article. for add array into database which way is better performance in PHP 5.4?!

- Add with PHP serialize into table
- Add with row columns(add row for each faq)

Comment: Also, `Add with` Google

Comment: Also, ask google for database normalization

Answer (score 0):

Serialization should be done in certain circumstances. Now I suggest you to use a row for each of your entries.

Following the Database Atomicity Principle, you have to have an entry for each of your data-node. It is strongly recommended to avoid putting a compilation of data into one DB entry. This principle assumes that each node saved to DB is too small and mostly could/should not be able to be split into more semantic segments. While serialization puts too many data-nodes into one serialized (type=string) node, and force it into DB (I say force to emphasize on its violation of DB's data atomicity).

Read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29

Assume the following scenario:

For instance you put "name&lastname&mobile" into one column of an entry. When using it, you use `explode("&", $data)` to explode them. This is not a good practice and you'd better avoid employing it. For such scenario, you should put `$name`, `$lastname` and `$mobile` separately into their respective columns (for each entry).

Now, in some situations, with regard to server, speed and project magnitude, you may use serialization. A side-note, WordPress uses serialization heavily. But Wordpress has many other awful practices, too.

In enterprise, statically significant application, they do not use such structure for one table:

```
Table users:

id name lastname mobile
```

They rather split the above one-table structures into four tables:

```
users:
id created_at updated_at

emails:
 id email user_id

names:
id name user_id

mobiles:
id mobile user_id
```

Using the above structure, for instance, you can trace how many did the user changed his name, mobile or lastname in a convenient way. I gave this example to show how much DB-saving could be far from the regularly done serialization.